# Reading a text file inn python and creating two lists out of it

Tags: python, list, text, save

I have a text file which has conversations say

```
person 1: "quotes"
person 2:"quotes2"
.
.
.
person 1:"quotes 3"
person 2:"quotes 4"
```

I want to read every quotes of person one and put it in a list and save it as a text file again. And another different list to save the quotes of person 2 and in another different file. How can I do it using python giving that each quote might be one line or more?

Comment: Hi Mee! Please share a small snippet of your file and specify how you want your 2 lists to be. I do not understand your question at this time. Also share the code which you have tried so far.

Comment: You can use a dictionary where the key is the person's name and the value is the list of that person's quotes.

Comment: @johny mopp: how can I check if the quote belongs to that person which supposed to be the key? given that the quote might be line or more?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - was out to lunch. I have typed up an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dictionary where the key is the author's name and the value is the list of their quotes. I would use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to make things easier. A benefit of using a dictionary is you can have an unknown number of authors.

```
from collections import defaultdict

filename = "your_path.txt"

# This is a dictionary of lists
quotes = defaultdict(list)

with open(filename) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    index = 0
    while index < len(lines):
        try:
            author, quote = lines[index].strip().split(':')
            # If it doesn't end in quote, keep reading until it does
            while not quote[-1] == '"':
                index += 1
                quote += "\n" + lines[index].strip()
            quotes[author].append(quote.strip('"'))
        except ValueError:
            pass
        index += 1

for key, value in quotes.items():
    print(f"{key}: {value}")
```

The output would be something like

```
person 1: ['quotes', 'quotes 3']
person 2: ['quotes2', 'quotes 4']
```

You can modify to write to a file instead of the console.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. however I get value error: ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
in this line         author, quote = line.split(':')

Comment: That means there is at least 1 line in the file that is not in the format "author:quote". I will update answer

Comment: yes this is because I mentioned that the quote might be one line or more. Is there a way to solve this?